# Show a piece of a Google Spreadsheet document on Andriod main screen

Tags: app-widgets, google-drive, scripts

I have a Google Spreadsheets document that is frequently updated and there are some cells in it that show a kind of short summary. Let it be a 2x2 block of cells that contains two headers and two values. I want to see those cells on the main screen of my Android 6 device as a widget to be able to check those values at a glance without actually opening the Spreadsheets app.

Is there any relatively simple way to get this result? A page of code on Google Apps Script and/or some tricky use of IFTTT maybe?

Comment: [this should help you](http://ask.metafilter.com/268789/Android-Widget-that-displays-Google-Spreadsheet-data)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many thanks to beeshyams. Here is a way to do what I wanted.

[This app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fahrbot.apps.metawidget) allows to parse chosen content from any web page and use it as a widget. In order to have a Spreadsheets document as a web page one can publish it (*File* → *Publish to the web...*). The cells of interest can be linked from another page of this document (or even from another document) using formulas like `=Sheet1!A1` so that the page being published would only contain what is expected to appear on the widget.

For now the widget I produced looks poor but there are plenty of customization capabilities including regexps and CSS so probably I will be able to tweak it according to my likings.

Comment: Welcome. Adding more details to your solution including detailed steps and snapshots to make it a fully self contained solution would be nice and add value, besides earning reputation +1

Comment: Is this still the only way 6 years later?

Comment: @boardtc Sorry I'm not up to date with this topic anymore as I moved from Android to Apple.