# Google Sheets cell value as a widget

Tags: applications, app-widgets, google-sheets

I would like to have some value from a cell in a google spreadsheets that is displayed on my android phone, a little bit like a KPI that I can track.
So I thought that there must be a way to add this as a widget. Only thing I found that seemed to be working was "Meta Widget" but the app is not on the play store anymore (ref:
[Show a piece of a Google Spreadsheet document on Andriod main screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/160505/show-a-piece-of-a-google-spreadsheet-document-on-andriod-main-screen)).

Any ideas on how to achieve this currently?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://ask.metafilter.com/268789/Android-Widget-that-displays-Google-Spreadsheet-data) Q&A page has an answer close to what you mentioned:

First, you can set up your Google Sheet to be "published," which essentially makes it a web page, so the caveat here is that you'll only want to add things to this page that you're okay with being publicly visible. The workaround here is to create a *new* sheet, [link only the relevant information](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/75943), then [publish](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/37579) this new sheet.

After that, the suggestion on the forum was Meta Widget as you suggested, but another (more recent) suggestion may be something like [Widgetify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.binarysmith.webclipwidget.ad), which I found in this [Computerworld article](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/256648/google-sheets-cell-value-as-a-widget).